# datetimepicker using gem bootsrtap saas not display properly include time in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker, saas

i using gem "bootstrap saas" and i implements bootstrap datetimepicker, but why the time not showing? and the datetimepicker showing in wrong position?

thanks before

Answer (score 0):

For datetime picker, you must add jquery-ui css and js file in your vendor/assets. And then write a script for datetimepicker, then only it will show correctly.